# Book about a girl who never dies and a man who killed everything he touches

Tags: story-identification, novel, love

I saw this romance novel on an instagram reel being advertised by the author about a girl who never dies and a man who kills everything he touches. It was in one of those "bound to falling in love" videos. Any ideas?

Comment: If gender-reversed is OK, https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11945589-cursed could fit too.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two suggestions but both have the genders switched. So I am detailing them below just in case they sound familiar - I can't think of any with the genders/powers split in the way you wrote.

The main one is Shatter Me by Tahereh Mafi. The main character is a girl who kills people with her touch by taking their energy. Suddenly she meets a dude who she can touch without killing (I think he was invincible or something). I've seen this book talked about recently even though it came out in 2011 the most common cover has a lot of purple.

The other one is more recent (2022) which is This Vicious Grace by Emily Thiede. Slightly different the girl can kill people with a touch but she doesn't kill everyone she touches (it's complicated) but the book opens with her at a funeral because she killed someone. The love interest is somewhat impervious to harm so they can touch without him dying. This one is more recent so more likely to be talked about now.